# What should I name a Java class that only has a getter?

Tags: java, class, getter, naming, conventions

I've set up a pluggable system that can retrieve numeric values from the system environment, which have no equivalent setters.

For example:

This interface specifies the contract of the retriever

```
public interface ValueRetriever
{
    double retrieveValue();
}
```

Here are two implementations:

```
public class TotalMemoryRetriever implements ValueRetriever
{
    @Override
    public double retrieveValue()
    {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    }
}

public class FreeMemoryRetriever implements ValueRetriever
{
    @Override
    public double retrieveValue()
    {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }
}
```

Other possibilities are to return system load, free disk space, etc.

I have built another layer which computes moving averages over different spans of time for the retrieved values, which is why it's useful to have an interface for the retrieval. That lets me use the moving averages mechanism with many "retriever" implementations by "plugging in" each specific retriever.

I have chosen the term "retriever" for this, but my sense is there may be a better term or a better way to do this. Is there a best practice or other convention I can use here?

Comment: Single method classes are very common in Java. The logic of the code looks fine. Perhaps in place of `value` you can come up with a more descriptive name. What *is* the value that is being returned? The total amount of free memory? Then call the method `retrieveFreeMemory()` and the class `FreeMemoryRetriever` or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could name the classes `TotalMemorySensor` and `FreeMemorySensor` and make them both implement a `MemorySensor` interface.

I'm not sure if the same interface should be used for RAM, CPU, disk, and other statistics. What does it even mean to retrieve a `double`? Is it KB, MB, GB? It feels like `DiskSensor` should have `long totalSpaceInBytes()` while the `CpuSensor` should have `double loadAverage(TimeUnit)`.

A `ValueRetriever` can mean anything and we already have a [`DoubleSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleSupplier.html).

Comment: Good question. The "sensor" returns the amount of the value in its native units, which for memory would be bytes, for load would be a fraction from 0 to 1, etc.  I chose type double because for all real world measurable values in a PC, all values of an integer and all realistic values held in a long can be represented accurately by a double. And because this is part of a system monitoring package, only a few digits of precision are really necessary.

I now realize I can avoid needing multiple versions of the tracking/averaging mechanism for different types simply by making it generic.